# call a variable created in an event function in wx python

Tags: python, variables, wxpython

I created a variable (snowDIR) via GetPath inside a wx.DirDialog box and I would like to use snowDIR outside the function. There is a sample of my code:

```
for file in os.listdir(snowDIR):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.hdf'): 
                if file[9:16] == a: 
                    inputhdf =  (snowDIR + '\\' + file) 
                    print 'input hdf is: ', inputhdf
                    tmod = 1

def OnDownload(self, e):
    modisPathFile = 'MODIS_data_directory_path.txt'
    dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:",
                       style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE
                       #| wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST
                       #| wx.DD_CHANGE_DIR
                       )

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        print "You chose %s" % dlg.GetPath()
        snowDIR = dlg.GetPath()
        print 'snowDIR : ', snowDIR
        dlg.Destroy()

more code ....

return snowDIR
```

any help would be greatly appreciated since I've search the net without lock and I'm getting out of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign it to `self.snowDir` and you can access it from your object and from anything that has access to it! e.g.:

```
def OnDownload(self, e):
    modisPathFile = 'MODIS_data_directory_path.txt'
    dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:",
                       style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE
                       #| wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST
                       #| wx.DD_CHANGE_DIR
                       )

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        print "You chose %s" % dlg.GetPath()
        self.snowDIR = dlg.GetPath()
        print 'snowDIR : ', self.snowDIR
        dlg.Destroy()
```

**In the same scope** - *i.e. as part of the same object:*

```
def OnDoitClick(self, event):
    """ Do the action that uses snowDir """
    self.MOD01_dir = os.path.join(self.snowDIR,'MOD01')
    ....
```

**Outside the scope:** *Assuming that the above code is a part of the class definition of *`MyFrameClass`  *and that your App uses* `TheFrame = MyFrameClass(...)` *at the same level as the above you can use*:

```
if hasattr(TheFrame, snowDIR):
   print 'snowDIR', TheFrame.snowDIR
else:
   print 'User did not set snowDIR'
```

Comment: I have changed all the snowDIR for self.snowDIR with this result:
    self.MOD01_dir = os.path.join(self.snowDIR,'MOD01')
    AttributeError: 'PanelSNOW' object has no attribute 'snowDIR'
I then try to assign self.snowDIR to a new value, with about the same result:
    snowDIR2 = self.snowDIR        
AttributeError: 'PanelSNOW' object has no attribute 'snowDIR'